# How to solve PHPExcel out of memory error?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to generate Excel reports:

- I have a report which is around 600kb
- The report has 15 sheets
- Each sheets contains approximately 200 rows and 12 columns.
- One sheet contains formulas.
- I am using PHPExcel for both reading and writing.
- I am using amazon free web tier server
- I am having approximately 600MB RAM in the server

The problem is that the process writing to the excel file is getting killed (due to out of memory)

What should I do? Are there any other Excel libraries available? I want a library with both read and write capabilities.

Is there another way to solve the out of memory problem?

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe that a 600kb file run through PHPExcel would fill up 600MB of memory. It's probably just the memory allocated to PHP that runs out. You can increase the memory available to PHP scripts by using one of these methods:

- Adding `memory_limit = 16M` to your php.ini file (recommended, if you have access)
  With root access, you can use the sed util in Linux/Unix based systems, in order to increase the memory for 64M. Don't forget to properly locate your php.ini file!
  `sed -i 's/memory_limit = .*/memory_limit = 64M/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
- Adding `ini_set('memory_limit', '16M');` to your php script
- Adding `php_value memory_limit 16M` to your .htaccess file in the root folder of your project

Comment: Well I am not using web interface..I am running phpexcel from the command line..its just taking the data from the local database and writing it into the excel file..I am not using web any where so there is no point in "Adding php_value memory_limit 16M to your .htaccess file"...so for the commad line access also i will have to set memory_limit? i tested the code in my local machine and it was taking approx 258 mb RAM ..here is my code for memory_test..http://pastebin.com/Lb4jZwiB

Comment: Okay, but you could still use any of the first two methods and when you run scripts from the command line you can also start them with the following flag `-d memory_limit=300M`

Comment: but in my cli/php.ini file memory_limit is set to -1 and it is also saying that Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = -1

Comment: so what is the solution? memory_limit=-1 means php will not impose any memory restriction ..so what should be the next step?

Comment: You could [post relevant parts of your code](http://pastebin.com), maybe there's something that can be improved. To me, 258MB still seems like a lot.

Comment: Also make sure that you are using the latest version of PHPExcel, since the developers seems to be making a continous effort of minimizing memory usage.

Comment: What I did was limit the amount of data output. Instead of dumping 1000 records from the database i put it out in chunks of 250. Not ideal but I couldn't think of any other way.